# What book or online resource do you suggest to learn programming C++ in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I have years of C++ programming experience in Windows. Now I need to program some applications for Linux. Is there any resource that helps me quickly get the required information about Linux technologies available to C++ developers?

Comment: Are you more interested in libraries which provide similar functionality to windows ones, the use of Unix utilities (grep, awk, sed, make, man etc.), or developer IDEs/tools?

Comment: When i wrote the question I had the libraries in mind but i should say that I need to get familiar with libraries, tools, developer IDEs, technologies that are not available in windows and etc.

Any information regarding moving from windows programming to Linux will be a great help to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programming in C++ under Linux isn't all that different at the core.  Linux compilers are generally more standard's conforming than MSVC; however, that is changing as MSVC is becoming a better compiler.  The difference is more from the environment and available libraries.  Visual Studio isn't available (obviously) but some other environments like [Visual SlickEdit](http://slickedit.com/) and [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) are available on both.

The build system is widely varied and will probably be dictated by your preference between Gnome, KDE, or the ever-present command line.  Personally, I find the latter to be the cleanest and most consistent.  If you end up at the command line, then learn [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and pick up a copy of [GNU Autoconf, Automake, and Libtool](http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/).  This will introduce the GNU command line development stack pretty nicely.

Debugging is a lot different being that VS provides a nice GUI debugging environment.  Most Linux environments simply wrap a command line debugger (usually gdb) with a GUI.  The result is less than satisfactory if you expect a nicely integrated debugger.  I would recommend getting comfortable with gdb.  There are some [decent tutorials](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) [for gdb online](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gdb/).  Just [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=debugging+with+gdb) for a bunch of them.  Once you get a little comfortable, [read the online manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_toc.html) for the really neat stuff.

The other choice is to use whatever development environment is packaged with your windowing system or to use something like [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) and [some C++ plug-in](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-793.html)

As for books on the subject, [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.kohala.com/start/apue.html) is a must-read.  [UNIX Systems Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130424110) is also a good read since it gives you a solid grounding in shells, processes, and what not.  I would recommend both the [POSIX Programmer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0937175730) and [POSIX.4 Programmer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565920740) since they give you a lot of the systems programming stuff.

With all of that said, enjoy your foray into an operating system that really cater to programmers ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the process of making the switch from Windows to Linux right now for a program and so far I have found that `man` and `grep` are great.  Instead of looking up function prototypes in MSDN (or similar) I just use `man`.

If I need a code example, `grep`ing through an existing project that has some similarities to mine is a great help.  Or if there is a project similar enough to warrant this, setting up an [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/) of their code-base to more easily facilitate reading really helps a lot.

In general, the open source nature of Linux has been the greatest resource to learning to program on Linux.

Also Stevens' [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201563177) was a huge boon.  But as for IDE's and the like, call me a luddite, but I just like `vim` and `make`.

Comment: LXR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXR_Cross_Referencer

Answer (score 2):

I've learned a lot from [Beginning Linux Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147628) by Matthew and Stones, though it's more C than C++.

Answer (score 1):

I use die.net and lookup at [The Open Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Open_Group)'s website a lot, http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/{function}.html. They have much the same information as [man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page). I use SciTE, and have the C API and The Open Group POSIX lookup as hotkeys, as described [here](http://www.tincancamera.com/blog/2009/01/scite-and-ctags.html).